# Keep $dirty status of form input field when switching views with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angular-ui-router

Is there an easy way to keep the $pristine / $dirty status of input fields inside a form which is wrapped around a nested view when switching the nested view?

My app has the following structure:

```
<div ui-view> <!-- main view - this stays active -->

  <div ng-form="form.product">

    Some content

    <div ui-view></div> <!-- sub view - this changes and holds different parts of the form -->

    <!--
    the content of this inner view (its template) looks something like this:

    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel.someProperty"/>
    -->

  </div>

</div>
```

The controller which holds the form data is on the outer view controller. When I switch the tabs (and therefore the content of the inner view), the values of the inner input elements always show the correct values. I can update the values, everything works fine, except one thing: The validation status is being reset.

When I change an input field, the outer form and the inner input elements get $dirty - but when I switch the inner view and then back again, the outer form is still $dirty *but the inner input element is $pristine again*, even though the input elements still hold the changed values and the outer form is still $dirty.

I think the input elements $dirty/$pristine status is being reset when the inner view is unloaded and then loaded again, although their values being updated immediately with the model values from the outer form when they come into view.

Is there an easy way to keep the $dirty status when I switch to another view without much additional code (like keeping track of changes to every singe input element by myself)?

Comment: save `form.product` in service or session storage,

Comment: @HarishR Could you please explain further how that would help? The `form.product` object is set inside the outer view controller, so it should be available to all the sub views, right?